# How to load an icon from resources to a TImage?

Tags: image, delphi, resources, delphi-10.3-rio

I try the following code and it's not working... `LoadIconWithScaleDown` returns a negative error code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LoadResToImg(RID: String; const Img: TImage);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$R UserResources.res}

uses Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.LoadResToImg(RID: String; const Img: TImage);
var Ico: TIcon;
    hI: HICON;
    HR: HResult;
begin
 Ico:= TIcon.Create;
 HR:= LoadIconWithScaleDown(HInstance, PChar(RID), Img.Width, Img.Height, hI);
 Ico.Handle:= hI;
 Img.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(Ico);
 Ico.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 LoadResToImg('OFFLINE', Image1);
end;

end.
```

UserResources.rc

```
OFFLINE      ICON    "gray_button.ico"
ONLINE       ICON    "green_button.ico"
```

Comment: You have a `const` on the image but not the string. It "should" be the opposite!

Comment: So the objects like `TImage` ar passed by reference even they don't have `const` ?

Comment: Yes, objects are always passed by reference. Strings use COW semantics, and with `const` the compiler doesn't need to update the refcount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because the VCL's wrapper (in `Winapi.CommCtrl.pas`) for this Win32 function is faulty, or at least cannot be used straight away.

So instead declare it yourself:

```pascal
function LoadIconWithScaleDown(hinst: HINST; pszName: LPCWSTR; cx: Integer;
    cy: Integer; var phico: HICON): HResult; stdcall; external 'ComCtl32';
```

But beware that this function is only present on Windows Vista+ (IIRC).

Comment: Indeed, that's it ! It works now... Thanks ! It was driving me crazy for about 4 hours...

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `InitCommonControlsEx` before you use `LoadIconWithScaleDown`, but I don't think this is necessary from the Win32 point of view.

Comment: "*But beware that this function is only present on Windows Vista+ (IIRC).*" - in which case, you should include the [`delayed` keyword](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages_(Delphi)#Delayed_Loading_.28Windows-only.29) on the function declaration, and then simply not call the function at runtime on pre-Vista systems

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Or do it old-school: `LoadLibrary` + `GetProcAddress`. That's necessay if you are using an old version of Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand really old version, as `delayed` was introduced in D2010.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can also do the same thing using [`InitCommonControlsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex).
I think the approach in Andreas answer is simpler, but if someone prefer using `InitCommonControlsEx`, here is the code:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.CommCtrl;

...

var
  IconHandle : HICON;
  ICC: TInitCommonControlsEx;
begin
  ICC.dwSize := SizeOf(TInitCommonControlsEx);
  ICC.dwICC := ICC_BAR_CLASSES;

  if(not InitCommonControlsEx(ICC)) then
    raise Exception.Create('InitCommonControlsEx error');

  if(LoadIconWithScaleDown(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(<your res id>), 32, 32, IconHandle) <> S_OK) then
    raise Exception.Create('LoadIconWithScaleDown error');

  <here you can use IconHandle as you need>
end;
```

**Note:** I've tested it passing `IDI_INFORMATION` as `<your res id>`